# Installing a package on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, raspbian

I am using Raspbian, I am trying to install qTox messenger. I have downloaded the arm package. It looks like a purple diamond logo. I run ./qtox and it opens fine, runs perfect. How would I install this file instead of having to run it in the terminal everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Create a .desktop file for it.

Note: The newer versions of the Raspian don't have an "Everything else" category on the start menu, so in the .desktop, specify the category as one that currently exists on the start menu, eg. Sound & Video.

Don't know how to do that? Not a  problem: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en